# Python: How do I approximate a float when I convert to string?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, python-2.7

I have a timing module:

```
start_timing = time.time()
#stuff happening here    
report_timing["INT_MODULE"] = time.time()- start_timing
```

If I use `str(report_timing["INT_MODULE"])` what I get is the very long:`0.000441074371338`.

Is there a standard way to round this float to `0.0004` or other way to represent to less digits like `440 microseconds`, in other words, a standard way to convert time?

Comment: See [Displaying the output of a variable to more than 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325660/12325698#12325698)

Comment: For precise timing, use [`timeit.default_timer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer); it'll use the correct timer on all platforms.

Comment: For microsecond handling, simply divide the value by 1000 and print that value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try some string formatting:

```
In [1]: strs=0.000441074371338

In [2]: "{0:e}".format(strs)
Out[2]: '4.410744e-04'

In [3]: "{0:.4f}".format(strs)
Out[3]: '0.0004'

In [9]: "{0:.0f} us".format(strs*1000*1000)
Out[9]: '441 us'
```

Answer (score 1):

report_timing["INT_MODULE"] = int((time.time() - start_timing)*1000.0) / 1000

Answer (score 0):

You can round a long with the default built-in function;
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

As for converting it to micro-seconds, I'm afraid I can't help.